# Dynamically set '#prefix' => '<div id="wrapper_id">'

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a form with a select field (where you can select a title of a novel). This select field automatically writes a value (the rspective ISBN of the novel) into a textfield when a novel is chosen by the user.
This all works very well:

```
$form['fieldset-books'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Books'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="books-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => ' </div>',
  ];

$form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Novels'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="novels-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => ' </div>',
      ];
$form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Title'),
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#options' => NOVEL_TITLE,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'isbn_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'isbn_wrapper',
        'event' => 'change',
      ],
    ];

$form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['isbn'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('ISBN'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'placeholder' => t('- will be automatically assigned -'),
      'readonly' => 'readonly',
    ],
    '#prefix' => '<div id="isbn_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

function isbn_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['title']) and
    $form_state['values']['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['title'] !== '') {
    $isbn = ISBN[array_search($form_state['values']['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['title'],
      array_keys(NOVEL_TITLE))];
  }
  else {
    $isbn = NULL;
  }
  $form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['isbn']['#value'] = $isbn;
  return $form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels']['isbn'];
}
```

Now i'd like to add more of these two fields (novels)  dnaymically. So i thought of adding a button for adding these fields.

```
$form['fieldset-books']['novel_add'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Add Novel'),
      '#name' => 'AddNovelButton',
      '#submit' => ['ajax_submit'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'books-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn-primary btn-sm']],
    ];
```

And the respective callback and submit functions.

```
function ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'AddNovelButton') {
    return $form['fieldset-books'];
  }
  return NULL;
}

function ajax_submit($form, &$form_state) {
if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'AddNovelButton') {
    if (!isset($form_state['count_novels'])) {
      $form_state['count_novels'] = 0;
      $form_state['count_novels']++;
    }
    $form_state['count_novels']++;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

And i put all this in a for loop, so when rebuilding the page, the correct amount of novels is shown.

```
if (empty($form_state['count_novels'])) {
    $form_state['count_novels'] = 1; 
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['count_novels']; $i++) {
    $form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels'][$i] =
      // novels fieldset (see above)

    $form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels'][$i]['title'][$i] =
      // title select field (see above)

    $form['fieldset-books']['fieldset-novels'][$i]['isbn'][$i] =
      // isbn text field (see above)

  }
  $form['fieldset-books']['novel_add'] =
    // novel add button (see above)
```

This works also in principle but of course, in added novels, the automatic assignment of the ISBN does not work, because all added novels still reference the `isbn_wrapper`. I tried to set the `'#prefix' => '<div id="isbn_wrapper">',` to a dynamic variable tied to `$form_state['count_novels']`, but it didnt work.

Is there a way to set `'#prefix' => '<div id="isbn_wrapper">'` dynamically so the assignment of the ISBN works for added novels? Or is there an entirely different problem?

Comment: You could maybe try having just 1 ajax callback for both actions. So you could try making both use ajax_callback and move your isbn logic into that callback along with your add a novel stuff. That way you wouldn't need to worry about having a ID for each isbn item

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem with the wrapper ID. :)